# Is there a Tatsu or any PEG-format grammar available for the [g]awk language syntax?

Tags: awk, grammar, peg, tatsu

As the subject asks, does anyone know of an existing Tatsu grammar (or at least a PEG-format grammar) for the [g]awk language?

I did already browse all existing Tatsu examples that I could find, and searched extensively around the net for any PEG-format grammar for the requested language.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If there's an ANTLR grammar for AWK, you can start with the TatSu `g2e` converter.

If there is a grammar for AWK in any other grammar language, the shortest route is to write a grammar`->`grammar translator, as grammar languages tend to be small enough to be treatable with little effort.

Moving a grammar that was originally LR, LL, or LLA to PEG+LEFTREC takes just a little *more* effort.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but unfortunately there does not seem to be an ANTLR grammar for any variety of the AWK language.  The only grammar available seems to be the yacc/lex grammar in the GNU gawk source tree.

Comment: A translator from YACC to TatSu should be useful for this and other cases.